# Create multiple symfony 4 forms in the same view

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have a symfony 4 application that has multiple forms on the same page.
However because they use the same formType, only one renders with the correct inputs.

There is one create form, and multiple update forms which are triggered when the user clicks a modal.  I render the update forms on the page by calling a twig include then passing the item id into the partial.  The partial then renders the same form as the create form but with the values from the passed object.

Is there any way of achieving this?

A basic representation of the current view:

```
{#create form#}
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}

{#update form1#}
{{ form_start(, {'action': path('edit', { "id" : update.id }),  'attr': {'id' : dealer.id}}) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}

{#update form2#}
{{ form_start(, {'action': path('edit', { "id" : update.id }),  'attr': {'id' : dealer.id}}) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

I would like to use the same controller methods for CRUD and have tried creating a Form\AbstractType for each update entity but didn't have any luck!

Comment: If possible, show some sample code on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Have just given a rough example, thank you

Comment: I think you should initialize your form twice into different twig variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of sending all the forms same name, change to names, formRead, formUpdate, FormDelete etc..
The last $form will override self to one before.

```
{% if formRead is defined %}
{#create form#}
{{ form_start(formRead) }}
{{ form_widget(formRead) }}
{{ form_end(formRead) }}
{% end if %}

{% if formUpdate is defined %}
{#update form1#}
{{ form_start(formUpdate, {'action': path('edit', { "id" : update.id }),  'attr': {'id' : dealer.id}}) }}
{{ form_widget(formUpdate) }}
{{ form_end(formUpdate) }}
{% end if %}
```

Comment: Would this work if i had 10 update forms (with the relevant input values) on the page?

Comment: Instead of 10 updates forms, Why you are not using CollectionType.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue ...
In my page I have many articles, for each article I need to display the same form (with its action modified) to add a comment.
So I try to render a controller sending a form with parameters to build a custom action. But The html form tag is only appearing once. The second article got labels and inputs without the form tag...

Comment: Embedded forms collection leads to a main form containing many forms, and they're submitted simultaneously ...
We don't want our forms to be contained in a main form, we want them appearing on their own, one by one, and submit them the same way.